# Ruby Inject Method Strange Output

Tags: ruby

Trying out a simple tutorial on ruby. In IRB, when i type the following code

```
(1..10).inject{|memo,n| memo + n} 
=>55 (correct calculation)
```

However, when I type the following:

```
(1..10).inject{|memo,n| memo + n*2} 
=>109 (which should be 110)
```

The calculation becomes wrong. What seems to be the problem when Ruby is performing the inject method?

Comment: It is not wrong. In what sense are you claiming it to be wrong? The question is not clear.

Comment: @sawa I thought it was wrong because in the first code, it was doing this:
    memo = 0
    memo+= 1
    memo+= 2
    .
    .
    memo+=10.
For the second code, everything should be times 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on ruby magic, that passes first enumerable element to `memo` when it is not specified explicitly, I would always go with explicit memo initialization:

```
#             ⇓⇓⇓ initial memo value
(1..10).inject(0) { |memo,n| memo + n*2 } 
#⇒ 110
```

Comment: I didn't know that memo will take the value of the first item of the range. I thought it will start with an empty container.

Comment: “Empty” is hard to predict. Consider `inject &:+` and `inject &:*`. For addition, `0` is the best candidate. For multiplication, `1` is.

Answer (score 1):

It's because at first time it assignes 1 to memo and 2 to n:

```
|memo, n| => memo = 1, n = 2
```

So, when you do simple add at first time it will 1+2 = 3, and then n goes through rest of numbers. Thus, n never becomes the first number.